# How can I set up working users in an AD LDS?

Tags: ad-lds

I need to set up a test Active Directory where I can freely change users and groups. After MUCH troubles I manged to set up the AD-LDS itself in a way that seems realistic to my uninitiated eyes. I've created some users but can't for the life of me find out how to set a password.

My structure is like this.

- CN=MyApp,DC=ORPLE,DC=CH ... *This is my Partition*

  - CN=Deleted Objects
  - CN=LostAndFound
  - CN=NTDS Quotas
  - CN=Roles
  - **CN=Users**
  - **CN=Groups**

I've modeled some users after what I've seen in our real AD except I can't seem to get them to work with my Test Program (Find and Authenticate a user).

Now all the guides I've found on the internet say I need to set the Password with the ADSI Edit program. Which I've done. twice. But it still doesn't work

What am I missing?

Here's the Screenshot of the User I'm trying to authenticate. I've created it using Active Directory Explorer from Sysinternals. In ADSI Edit I've right clicked that user and used "Reset Password".
[image: Example User Attributes]

To Authenticate I'm using the a small program based on [this MS KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316748/en). It works when operating on our actual Active Directory but not when I direct my program to my local AD-LDS instance.

I've also followed [this guide (from step 2 on)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robert_mcmurray/archive/2011/09/16/ftp-and-ldap-part-2-how-to-set-up-an-active-directory-lightweight-directory-services-ad-lds-server.aspx#02b) to create a new user and added it to the reader group. I then tried to connect to ADLDS in ADSI Edit using that user to confirm it was set up properly. But it didn't work.

Comment: Explain exactly what you've done, using ADSI edit. Include screenshots. Explain what leads you to think the password change isn't working.

Comment: @mfinni - I've added a screenshot of the user and elaborated on how I've tested it. As I'm a total noob in terms of AD I don't know what else would be relevant. Please elaborate if you need more info. Thank you!

Comment: Can you try binding to the AD LDS instance using an account in it, with the changed password, using ADSI Edit or AD Explorer? I don't know if the problem might be that the code you're using doesn't work with modern AD LDS.

Comment: @mfinni - ADSI Edit can't connect under that username either.